# How to in React return array without duplicates or sum duplicate objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting

Please help me to find a solution and a bit with my code refactoring.

I just want to put some objects from one array to a new and it will be like a product cart. That's why I don't want to see any duplicates but just: product - quantity in the modal window.
I've got two arrays:

```
state = {
  existData: [
    {
      productName: "CoolProductName 1",
      count: 0,
      image: "src.jpeg",
      author: "Name Surname",
      date: "21.02.2020",
      id: 1,
    },
    {
      productName: `CoolProductName 2"`,
      count: 0,
      image: "src.png",
      author: "Name Surname",
      date: "21.02.2020",
      id: 2,
    },
  ],
  addedToCart: [],
};
```

So, the function is:

```
added = (id) => {
  //get product Id from other component

  this.setState(({ addedToCart, existData }) => {
    let newObj = existData.filter((el) => el.id === id); // there is I get product selected by user from array of all products

    return {
      addedToCart: [...addedToCart, ...newObj],
    };
  });
};
```

With my little knowledge I thought to do something like:

```
let newObj = existData
  .filter((el) => el.id === id)
  .map((el) => {
    if (el.count >= 0) {
      el.count++;
    }
    return { ...el };
  });
```

yes it returns value with the `count++` but in `addedToCart` array I've got duplicates objects with different counts.
I see two ways:

1. remove duplicates in `addedToCart` array after add an object to the cart and increase count then just show something like `{addedToCart.prductName} - {addedToCart.count}` in the cart.
2. count duplicate objects and remove count field.

What is the better way and suitable code? Thank you

Comment: There is solution suitable to me:
` added =  (id) => {

  this.setState (( { addedToCart, dataList  } )=>{
  // filter return an Array but
  // find return an element, what we are looking for by id
  const newItem = dataList.find(el=>el.id===id);
  const mainArr = [...addedToCart ];
  // if there is no in shopping cart
  if(mainArr.find(el=>el.id===id) == undefined){
    newItem.count = 1;
    mainArr.push(newItem);
  }
  // if exist then count ++
  else{
    mainArr.find(el=>el.id===id).count++;
  }
  
  return{      
    addedToCart: mainArr
  } 
})};
`

Answer (score 2):

I would keep aside `count` from product Details. Also, `addedToCart` would be an object, where its key are the ids with and the value is the `count`;

new state format:

```
state = {
  existData: [
    {
      productName: "CoolProductName 1",
      image: "src.jpeg",
      author: "Name Surname",
      date: "21.02.2020",
      id: 1,
    },
    {
      productName: `CoolProductName 2"`,
      image: "src.png",
      author: "Name Surname",
      date: "21.02.2020",
      id: 2,
    },
  ],
  addedToCart: {}, //store id and count here
};
```

this way `added` would check for id keys to update its count:

```
added = (id) => {
  //get product Id from other component
  this.setState(({ addedToCart }) => {
    const count = typeof addedToCart[id] === "undefined" ? 1 : ++addedToCart[id];
    return { addedToCart: { ...addedToCart, [id]: count } };
  });
};
```

This way you avoid any object duplication, and segregates cart's items from product details. If you need to access a product's count you can check `this.state.addedToCart[id]` if it exists and return its `count` accordingly.

basic implementation example:

[image: cart-example]

Answer (score 0):

According to React docs, setState should be like: setState(updater, [callback]),

If I'm not mistaken, your are passing a callback in the place of the updater.

It should look like `this.setState({ state: 'something' }, () => { console.log('something') })`

React does not accept calling new functions with pre existents Components names.